# How to alias / rewrite path to theme?

Tags: path-aliases

The paths to css/js/images in a theme look like /sites/mysite.org/theme/*

Is there a way to rewrite those paths to – let's say – /mytheme/* ?

Comment: htaccess rewrite

Comment: @Aboodred1 yeah but that does it just one way

Comment: Can you expand a little on why you need this?  That may help you get better answers or alternatives.

Comment: @MPD Just one more point on the unreachable goal of not telling the the webz you are using drupal :)

Comment: @redben That's **impossible** and pointless, please don't waste your time on this.

Comment: @user11153 sorry ? why pointless ? as MPD says : hook_url_inbound/outbound_alter do the trick.

Comment: It's basically impossible to hide the fact that your site uses Drupal. The `Drupal.settings` JS var in every page is a dead give away and requires some serious re-plumbing to remove. What @user11153 is saying is that trying to implement security through obscurity is effort wasted - far better that time be spent in more productive areas

Comment: Guys i know it is impossible to hide drupal, if you reread my comment it says "...unreachable goal of not telling the the webz you are using drupal". Come on. Still, you can always raise the bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL mappings can be altered with two hooks: [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) and [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).

`hook_url_inbound_alter()` is used for paths that Drupal is responding to.  See [`drupal_get_normal_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7).

`hook_url_outbound_alter()` is used for paths constructed by [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7).

Whether or not you can accomplish this will require some experimentation, as I don't know how the theme registry will complicate matters.

Comment: Was hoping there was a module out there that does it. Looks like I'll have to dive n code again. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Keep in mind that, with the .htaccess file Drupal uses, serving files don't involve Drupal, but the Apache server. Drupal handles only those paths that don't lead to any existing file; this means that these hooks are not invoked when the path is for an existing file.